# Shared mutable state in Hyper

Tags: rust, hyper, rust-tokio

I'm trying to create a counter in a Hyper web server that counts the number of requests it has received. I'm using a `Arc<Mutex<u64>>` to hold onto count. However, I haven't been able to figure out the right combination of `move` and `.clone()` to satisfy the types of the closures. Here's some code that compiles, but resets the counter on each request:

```
extern crate hyper;

use hyper::rt::Future;
use hyper::service::service_fn_ok;
use hyper::{Body, Response, Server};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

fn main() {
    let addr = "0.0.0.0:3000".parse().unwrap();
    // FIXME want to create the counter here, not below
    let server = Server::bind(&addr)
        .serve(|| {
            service_fn_ok(|_req| {
                let counter = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));
                use_counter(counter)
            })
        })
        .map_err(|e| eprintln!("Error: {}", e));
    hyper::rt::run(server)
}

fn use_counter(counter: Arc<Mutex<u64>>) -> Response<Body> {
    let mut data = counter.lock().unwrap();
    *data += 1;
    Response::new(Body::from(format!("Counter: {}\n", data)))
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It turns out I was pretty close, and looking at a few other examples helped me realize the problem. Since there are two layers of closures at play here, I need to move the `counter` into the outer closure, clone it, and then move that clone into the inner closure and clone there again. To wit:

```
extern crate hyper; // 0.12.10

use hyper::rt::Future;
use hyper::service::service_fn_ok;
use hyper::{Body, Response, Server};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};

fn main() {
    let addr = "0.0.0.0:3000".parse().unwrap();
    let counter = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));
    let server = Server::bind(&addr)
        .serve(move || {
            let counter = counter.clone();
            service_fn_ok(move |_req| use_counter(counter.clone()))
        })
        .map_err(|e| eprintln!("Error: {}", e));
    hyper::rt::run(server)
}

fn use_counter(counter: Arc<Mutex<u64>>) -> Response<Body> {
    let mut data = counter.lock().unwrap();
    *data += 1;
    Response::new(Body::from(format!("Counter: {}\n", data)))
}
```

---

**Update February 2020** Here's a version using hyper 0.13:

```
use hyper::{Body, Response, Server, Request};
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use hyper::service::{make_service_fn, service_fn};
use std::convert::Infallible;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let addr = "0.0.0.0:3000".parse()?;
    let counter = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0));

    let make_service = make_service_fn(move |_conn| {
        let counter = counter.clone();
        async move {
            Ok::<_, Infallible>(service_fn(move |_req: Request<Body>| {
                let counter = counter.clone();
                async move {
                    Ok::<_, Infallible>(use_counter(counter))
                }
            }))
        }
    });

    Server::bind(&addr).serve(make_service).await?;
    Ok(())
}

fn use_counter(counter: Arc<Mutex<u64>>) -> Response<Body> {
    let mut data = counter.lock().unwrap();
    *data += 1;
    Response::new(Body::from(format!("Counter: {}\n", data)))
}
```

Comment: I've provided a hyper 0.13 version as well

Comment: 0.13 code provided does compile and run, found that the counter would increase by 2.